# How to make the for-loop code faster with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, for-loop

I would like to make it faster with my imaging processing code.

**The task**

- preparing 2 images (img_kido_dx, img_kido_dy)
- preparing 2 gradient of the light (Rpg_grad_p, Rpg_grad_q)
- Calculate the 2x2 matrix H which has some information at each pixel.

** Algorithm**

> - matE = [[E_x1,E_x2,...E_xn], [E_y1,E_y2,...E_yn]]
> - matR = [[R_p1,R_p2,...R_pn], [R_q1,R_q2,...R_qn]]
> - matM = inv(matR)
> - matH = matE x matM

I tried to write a code with for loop. but it was so slow. it took over 30 sec.

Would you please give me information on how to make it faster with NumPy and other methods?

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np

N_ROW = 1080
N_COL = 1920
N_light = 20


img_kido_dx = np.empty((N_ROW * N_COL, N_light)) 
img_kido_dy = np.empty((N_ROW * N_COL,N_light))
Rpq_grad_p = np.empty((N_ROW  * N_COL,N_light))
Rpq_grad_q = np.empty((N_ROW * N_COL,N_light))



for i in range(N_ROW * N_COL):

    mat_E = np.array([img_kido_dx[i, :], img_kido_dy[i, :]])
    mat_R = np.array([Rpq_grad_p[i, :], Rpq_grad_q[i, :]])

    mat_M = np.linalg.pinv(mat_R)

    mat_H = np.matmul(mat_E, mat_M)
```

Comment: Your [mcve] contains typos -- you define variables `Rpg_grad_p` and `Rpg_grad_q` and then later on refer to variables `Rpq_grad_p` and `Rpq_grad_q` (notice the difference in the third character - `g` vs `q`)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the misspelling. Rpq is right.

Comment: If you have at least numpy 1.14, then [`linalg.pinv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) can work on stacks of matrices. i.e. you can give it an array of shape `(N_ROW*N_COL,2,20)`. [`matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) also works on stacks. [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) followed by reshape can make such stacks. https://pastebin.com/N06ZU1Uy (NB: wrote that before you made the correction, so I went with Rpg).

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your code showed over 20 times faster that original one.